# ConstraintLayout: How do I flatten this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

Is it possible to flatten this layout (only have one `ConstraintLayout` outside) and preserve the following:

- `MaterialCardView` keeps it square shape and an overall padding of 10dp
- `ImageView` is centered over some squared `View` (having the background set to a filled oval achieving its cicle-look)
- `ImageView` has a fixed ratio of width/height relative the squared `View`
- `TextView` is positoned below the squared `View` with a vertical distance of 10dp
- The squared `View` is centered horizontally inside (or then maybe over?) the `MaterialCardView`

How it looks right now and should continue to look:

[image: layout result]

The current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:strokeColor="@color/primaryColor"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/imageViewContainer"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".58"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".58"
                    app:tint="@color/primaryTextColor"
                    tools:src="@drawable/ic_qrcode" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewContainer"
                tools:text="ItemName" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: quick way is to replace `ConstraintLayouts` with simple `<View />`  and lift children on the same level as those `Views` and treat them as containers

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove parent `ContraintLayout`, let the `MaterialCardview` be the parent.
2. Then keep only one `ConstraintLayout` since its required if u want to have multiple views inside `MaterialCardView`.
3. The second `ConstraitLayout` aka `imageViewContainer` can be transformed into `View` and still it will be pretending to be a container.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/imageViewContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_rounded"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".58"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".58"
            app:tint="@color/gray"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_close" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewContainer"
            tools:text="ItemName" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: If I let the `MaterialCardview` be the root, how do I make it having a 1:1 ratio? `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` is only available if the element is inside a `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: u prolly dont need this ratio anyway